# Multi row to a row sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as bellow:
[image]

I want query to print output as bellow:
[image]

Comment: Welcome on SO. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please refer this: [ask]

Comment: Is it the same Pod_ID for those 3 rows? What's the expected result if a 4th rows with same id suddenly show up?

Comment: yes same Pod_ID for those 3 rows. I want query dynamic, if have 4th rows will show Pur_Qty3, Pur_Price3, ETD_Date3.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** *Please, do not downvote*. I know the rules of posting answers, but for such of questions there's no chance to post short answer. I posted it only to provide help for those who want to find out how to achieve that, but does not expect *ready-to-use* solution.

I'd suggest to read these articles:

[PIVOT on two or more fields in SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenobonn/2009/03/22/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server/)
[Pivoting on multiple columns - SQL Server](http://www.sqlideas.com/2015/04/pivoting-on-multiple-columns-sql-server.html) 
[Pivot two or more columns in SQL Server 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31551/Pivot-two-or-more-columns-in-SQL-Server)

Answer (score 1):

At first UNPIVOT then PIVOT. If number of rows for each `Pod_ID` is not always equal 3 then you need to use dynamic SQL. The basic sample:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  Pod_ID,
            Purs + CASE WHEN RN-1 = 0 THEN '' ELSE CAST(RN-1 as nvarchar(10)) END as Purs,
            [Values]
    FROM (
        SELECT  Pod_ID, 
                Pur_Qty, --All columns that will be UNPIVOTed must be same datatype
                Pur_Price, 
                CAST(ETD_Date as int) ETD_Date, -- that is why I cast date to int
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as RN
        FROM YourTable
        ) as p1
    UNPIVOT (
        [Values] FOR [Purs] IN(Pur_Qty, Pur_Price, ETD_Date)
    ) as unpvt
    ) as p2
PIVOT (
    MAX([Values]) FOR Purs IN (Pur_Qty,Pur_Price,ETD_Date,Pur_Qty1,Pur_Price1,ETD_Date1,Pur_Qty2,Pur_Price2,ETD_Date2)
) as pvt
```

Will bring you:

```
Pod_ID                                  Pur_Qty Pur_Price   ETD_Date    Pur_Qty1    Pur_Price1  ETD_Date1   Pur_Qty2    Pur_Price2  ETD_Date2
F8E2F614-75BC-4E46-B7F8-18C7FC4E5397    24      22          20160820    400         33          20160905    50          44          20160830
```